# Value matching in R

Tags: performance, r

I have three data frames `A`, `B` and `C`:

```
set.seed(0)
N <- 5
A<-data.frame(cbind(date=c(2,3,5,1), x=NA, id=sample(letters[1:2], 4, replace=T)), stringsAsFactors = F)
B<-data.frame(cbind(date=1:N, y=runif(N)), stringsAsFactors = F)
C<-data.frame(cbind(date=1:N, z=100+sample(N), id=rep(letters[1:2], N, replace=T)), stringsAsFactors = F)
C$z<-as.numeric(C$z)
```

and they look like this:

```
A
B
C
> A
  date    x id
1    2 <NA>  b
2    3 <NA>  a
3    5 <NA>  a
4    1 <NA>  b
> B
  date      y
1    1 0.9082
2    2 0.2017
3    3 0.8984
4    4 0.9447
5    5 0.6608
> C
   date   z id
1     1 104  a
2     2 101  b
3     3 105  a
4     4 103  b
5     5 102  a
6     1 104  b
7     2 101  a
8     3 105  b
9     4 103  a
10    5 102  b
```

I would like to fill in `A$x` with a function of `y` and `z`, let's say, for instance, the product of `B$y*C$z` for the corresponding `dates` and `ids`, like this:

```
for (i in 1:length(A$x)){
   A$x[i] <- B$y[A$date[i] == B$date] * C$z[A$date[i] == C$date & A$id[i] == C$id]
}
> A
  date                x id
1    2  20.369875034783  b
2    3 94.3309169216082  a
3    5 67.4013748336583  a
4    1 94.4536101594567  b
```

This is a very bad idea for a data set with many elements (obviously), as it is slow. I also tried with `match()` and `which()`, but there isn't any significant speed up, I believe. Maybe I could use `dcast()`, after merging everything into one data frame, but I would prefer not to merge the data frames at all (if this can be avoided).

Is it possible to do it more efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you mention that you don't want to merge the data frames,
your `for` loop could be replaced with this single line using merge:

```
with(merge(A, merge(B, C)), data.frame(date, x=y * z, id))
```

Given your example of `A`, `B`, `C`, this is returns a data frame:

> ```
>   date        x id
> 1    1 94.45361  b
> 2    2 20.36988  b
> 3    3 94.33092  a
> 4    5 67.40137  a
> ```

The problem with the for loop is that it's discouraged in R because it's inefficient.
Using merge should be fast.
I don't think you can get around merging,
as the meaning of your logic is in fact merging.